# How to make an SSH tunnel publicly accessible?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel

Referring back to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/517143/how-to-tunnel-a-local-port-onto-a-remote-server) question, I am executing the below via OpenSSH *(Client: Mac OS X 10.6 | Server: Linux Mint)*, however the port that is being tunneled is not working publicly:

```bsh
ssh -R 8080:localhost:80 -N root@example.com
```

- The purpose is so the local port can be opened on the remote computer
- It seems as if the remote side binds only on `localhost`, instead of to all interfaces
- It works when opening the port on `localhost` on the remote computer, but when trying to access the public IP of the remote computer from my local computer, the port doesn’t seem to be open

How would I make the tunnel public on the IP for anyone to access?

Comment: What does public IP mean? If you are trying to connect to a local computer thru the router and via the Internet, most routers will not allow such loopback.

Answer (score 473, accepted):

If you check the man page for ssh, you'll find that the syntax for `-R` reads:

```
-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
```

When *`bind_address`* is omitted (as in your example), the port is bound on the loopback interface only. In order to make it bind to all interfaces, use

```
ssh -R \*:8080:localhost:80 -N root@example.com
```

or

```
ssh -R 0.0.0.0:8080:localhost:80 -N root@example.com
```

or

```
ssh -R "[::]:8080:localhost:80" -N root@example.com
```

The first version binds to all interfaces individually. The second version creates a general IPv4-only bind, which means that the port is accessible on all interfaces via IPv4. The third version is probably technically equivalent to the first, but again it creates only a single bind to `::`, which means that the port is accessible via IPv6 natively and via IPv4 through [IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses) (doesn't work on Windows, OpenBSD).  (You need the quotes because `[::]` could be interpreted as a glob otherwise.)

Note that **if you use OpenSSH `sshd` server, the server's `GatewayPorts` option needs to be enabled** (`clientspecified`, or, in rare cases, to `yes`) for this to work (check file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server). Otherwise (default value for this option is `no`), the server will always force the port to be bound on the loopback interface only.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly why I always prefer `0.0.0.0` - it's IPv4 only, but it'll do most of the time :)

Comment: `fe80::1` hahaha

Comment: jk :D yea but 0.0.0.0 is good, but can you use 127.0.0.1? or is that too local and nonbinding

Comment: Well, actually `[::]` should work for all v4+v6! `127.0.0.1` means loopback, i.e. you're back to square one ;)

Comment: yea, i thought as much, but 0.0.0.0 will bind directly to the ipv4 interface so its not device specific

Comment: and `[::]` is only ipv6 right? How can it be used in ipv4?

Comment: No, `[::]` means `0:0:0:0:0....:0` and is essentially the IPv6 equivalent of `0.0.0.0` - but since IPv4 is basically a subset of IPv6 (e.g. `::ffff:10.120.78.40` is an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address), it'll mean the port is accessible both via IPv6 and IPv4.

Comment: well yea, i actualy jsut researched ipv6 for a half hour and now instead or `\*:` im using `[::0]:`

Comment: and instead of `localhost` im using `[::1]` works like a charm

Comment: I used -L instead of -R and it also works

Comment: GatewayPorts yes solved my problem.

Comment: GatewayPorts = yes (on the remote sshd config) fixed it for me too

Comment: "GatewayPorts yes" made my day, thanks @StefanSeidel

Comment: Note that **GatewayPorts yes** actually makes the *bind_address* irrelevant: "The argument may be [...], yes to force remote port forwardings to bind to the wildcard address"

Comment: By defautl "GatewayPorts" argument is not exist. Thank you pro!

Comment: `GatewayPorts yes` in my `~/.ssh/config` worked well in macOS

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
It make sense to add a note that user needs to restart `sshd` after the configuration update.

Comment: I was tripping for almost 30 mins because I did not read the entire answer. Gateway Ports yes worked

Comment: Never add "GatewayPorts" after a "Match" command (even if it is not indented) or you will go crazy! (cert from the manpage: "Only a subset of keywords may be used on the lines following a Match keyword")

Comment: Can you expand on "clientspecified, or, in rare cases, to yes"? Why should it generally not be yes (which seems to be what everyone is doing)?

Comment: GatewayPorts!!!!!! Why isn't this documented anywhere easily findable.???? I've been banging my head against the wall

Answer (score 46):

#### Edit:

`-g` works for local forwarded ports, but what you want is a reverse/remote forwarded port, which is different.

What you want is [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/379344/selecting-interface-for-ssh-port-forwarding).

Essentially, on `example.com`, set `GatewayPorts=clientspecified` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

#### --- previous (incorrect) answer ---

Use the -g option. From ssh's man page:

```
-g     Allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports.
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working... it starts up but i cant connect remotely

Comment: Try running `netstat -elnpt` from a separate tty to figure out what ports are bound to what address. Without `-g`, a port should be bound to `127.0.0.1:PORT`. With `-g`, it should be bound to `0.0.0.0:PORT`, which makes it accessible remotely.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/q6f4kJyd

Comment: `GatewayPorts=clientspecified` or `GatewayPorts clientspecified`

Comment: and do i add that to the client or remote?

Comment: already answered in the answer-- on _website.com_

Comment: ok, ill try now

Answer (score 19):

Here's my answer for completion:

I ended up using `ssh -R ...` for tunneling, and using `socat` on top of that for redirecting network traffic to `127.0.0.1`:

**tunnel binded to 127.0.0.1:**

`ssh -R mitm:9999:<my.ip>:8084 me@mitm`

**socat:**

`mitm$ socat TCP-LISTEN:9090,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:9999`

Other option is to do a local-only tunnel on top of that, but i find this **much** slower

`mitm$ ssh  -L<mitm.ip.address>:9090:localhost:9999 localhost`

Comment: I like the fact that I don't have to deal with the sshd configuration and that I can do all of it without sudo. Plus I learn that socat exists. Thanks!

Comment: +up you go good sir. I tried to tell ssh to bind to 0.0.0.0 without success.. then saw the \* syntax, tried that, no dice. I imagine it may be some sort of security feature on sshd config or something that isn't allowing it.

Finally saw this post and `socat` worked awesome. Super useful, putting this in my back pocket ;]

Answer (score 17):

You can also use a double forward if you won´t or can change /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

First forward to temporary port (e.g. 10080) on loopback device on the remote machine, then use local forward there to redirect port 10080 to 80 on all interfaces:

```
ssh -A -R 10080:localhost_or_machine_from:80 user@remote.tld "ssh -g -N -L 80:localhost:10080 localhost"
```

Comment: This actually works to bypass forwarding rules!

Comment: Love this solution. Great workaround when you don't want the change the config on the machine

Comment: It works, I have no idea WHY it works

Comment: if you got errors "Permission denied, please try again. Permission denied, please try again. usr@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password)." like me, use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16651742/2051938

Answer (score 8):

Use the "gateway ports" option.

`ssh -g -R REMOTE_PORT:HOST:PORT ...`

In order to use that, you probably need to add "`GatewayPorts yes`" to your server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: Actually this worked. What I do is that I use an EC2 instance as a forwarder to my REST server. This way, I don't need to stick my server in the DMZ and I don't need a public IP. Funny enough, with the first EC2 instance I created, ssh -R remote_port:localhost:port xxx@ec2xxx worked just fine but then I had to create another instance later on for some reason and from that point on, I was always getting: connection refused. Used tcpdump to look at what I was getting and there wasn't much info. -g plus GatewayPorts yes did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

[Jump hosts](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Jump_Hosts_--_Passing_Through_a_Gateway_or_Two) are a fairly recent addition to OpenSSH. This requires SSH access to the intermediate, but should work without additional configuration.

```
ssh -J root@example.com remoteuser@localhost -p 8080
```

This command instructs SSH to first connect to `root@example.com`, and then, from that machine, to initiate a connection to port 8080 at `localhost` (i.e., the port that is tunneled from the jump host to the remote host) under the `remoteuser` user name.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment at the appropriate sections, so I'm adding a new answer.

**Warning:** if you set `GatewayPorts` to `yes` this will make `sshd` bind your forwardings to any interface - regardless of the client configuration (`-R,` etc.). This can become quite a security issue if the client assumes she has limited her forwardings to f.e. localhost. Therefore, setting `GatewayPorts` to `clientspecified` is usually what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to put the configuration in you `~/.ssh/config` instead of using command line parameters, you can try something like

`Host REMOTE_HOST_NAME
    RemoteForward \*:8080 127.0.0.1:80`

Remember to have you remote host's firewall allow connections to 8080 and ensure that the `GatewayPorts` option of your `/etc/ssh/sshd` config isnt set to `no`