# Forward HTTP traffic to a server behind gateway

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, socat

I have a server behind gateway, which means it’s only pingable internally. Now I want to forward traffic from a outside server to this internal server. I want to use [`socat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/socat) like:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:8080, TCP:[internal server]:8080 # on external server
```

Which clearly won’t work because the IP address of that server is not available.

So how can I achieve this? I am open to any solutions.

Comment: I would look into using something like nginx as a reverse proxy.

Comment: @heavyd could you give me a hight-level explanation how reverse proxy works? how come it doesn't require that ip address? Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming the gateway box has access to both the internal and external networks.  Any reverse proxy would need to be run on the gateway.

Comment: @qqibrow re what a reverse proxy is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224664/difference-between-proxy-server-and-reverse-proxy-server

Comment: Why can't you use NAPT port forwarding on your gateway? btw, were you planning on running that socat line on an external server? also, socat aside, You could use this line from your internal server to external server 5.6.7.8 ssh -R 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 user@5.6.7.8 (format is PORT1:IP2:PORT2 user@IP1 that'd solve it4you.PORT1 is the port that will open listening on the comp you r calling ur external server.IP2:PORT2 is where2forward once it reaches the internal server i.e. forward it nowhere really(2itself).IP1 is'ext server'.The first but I am interested in other solutions though..!like socat!

Comment: @barlop u are right. the ssh tunnel works. :) the right solution is in this post: http://superuser.com/questions/588591/how-to-make-ssh-tunnel-open-to-public