# Trouble enabling GatewayPorts for Remote Port Forwarding over SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding

I'm trying to use an Ubuntu server to do remote port forwarding over `ssh`.

I've edited `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to contain the following lines at the bottom of the file:

```
...

Match User david
  GatewayPorts yes
  AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

Then I tried testing the config worked by rebooting the server, logging in and running the following:

```
sshd -T | grep -E 'gatewayports|allowtcpforwarding'
```

Unfortunately the result is:

```
gatewayports no
allowtcpforwarding yes
```

What am I missing to enable this so I can use remote port forwarding for testing local applications remotely?

```
ssh -R 8080:localhost:8080 david@example.com
```

Related:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115897/whats-ssh-port-forwarding-and-whats-the-difference-between-ssh-local-and-remot
- https://serverfault.com/questions/379344/selecting-interface-for-ssh-port-forwarding
- [How to make ssh tunnel open to public?](https://superuser.com/questions/588591/how-to-make-ssh-tunnel-open-to-public)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sshd -T -C user=david,host=localhost,addr=127.0.0.1 \
 | grep -E 'gatewayports|allowtcpforwarding'
```

should return correct values for your user.

Comment: Great! I am not sure why I didn't think about context being needed. However, the [sshd manpage](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8) states that user, host, and addr are all required so I modified your string: `sshd -T -C user=david,host=localhost,addr=127.0.0.1 | grep -E 'gatewayports|allowtcpforwarding'`

Comment: Thanks for the note. I forgot that all of them are need. Fixed now.