# sshd GatewayPorts always “no”

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sshd

As [Trouble enabling GatewayPorts for Remote Port Forwarding over SSH](https://superuser.com/questions/1091163/trouble-enabling-gatewayports-for-remote-port-forwarding-over-ssh) is not really solving my problem, I dare to ask:

I run a server on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

I need to set the option `GatewayPorts` to `yes`.

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I added the line

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

but it has no effect.

Neither `service ssh reload` nor `reboot` helps.

The output of

```
sshd -T -C user=me,host=localhost,addr=IP | grep -E "gatewayports"
```

results always in `gatewayports no`.

Even `sshd -T -C user=he,host=localhost,addr=127.0.0.1 | grep -E "gatewayports"` has the same output.

bug or what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is `GatewayPorts no` earlier in the file; if so, delete it.

Options that cannot take multiple values are set according to their first occurrence.