# Expose a mysql server over an ssh tunnel

Tags: networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I've used remote and local forwarding with succes in the past, but this time I can't get a setup to work.

What I'm trying to achieve:
Make my sql server publicly reachable so the Google CloudSql can replicate the database.

I have a NAS running debian behind a router that can do port mapping at location A
I am at location B with an CentOS VM running mariadb

From the VM at location B I run the following command

```
:~$ ssh -f -N -T -R 3306:localhost:3306 my.dyndns.address -p [sshport]
```

(no mysql server is running on the nas, or at least not at port 3306)

Then on the nas:

```
:~# ss -anp | grep :330
tcp    LISTEN     0      128    127.0.0.1:3306                  *:*                   users:(("sshd",pid=27182,fd=9))
tcp    LISTEN     0      128     ::1:3306                 :::*                   users:(("sshd",pid=27182,fd=8))
```

On the router I have port 33006 forwarded to the nas's port 3306 like so:

(columns protocol, external-start-port, external-end-port,local-port,destination[image: port forwarding router]
Other port forwarding rules like openvpn and ssh work perfectly that way

I can connect from my own computer to the mysql database, the directive `bind-address` was set to '*', I tried also with this directive commented, but as expected, yielded no different results

I'm looking at both machine's output from `journalctl -f`, but no information is coming through that can help me to troubleshoot what I'm doing wrong.

--- Clarification ---

1. I want to connect from the outside to `my.dyndns.address` at port `33006`.
2. `my.dyndns.address` translates to the public address from my ISP modem.
3. `33006` is forwarded on the modem to the local IP of the NAS at port 3306, which is in turn tunneled to the mysql-server (at location B).
4. I'm testing this with

   ```
   mysql -h my.dyndns.address --port=33006 -u myuser -p
   ```

   whereas

   ```
    mysql -h local_ip_on_B -u myuser -p
   ```

   works just fine

I also tried using a VPN from the db server at location B to location A (the NAS is also the OpenVpn server) and pointing the forwarded port on the ISP's modem directly to IP Address of the IP the db server gets on the tun interface. If I make a second VPN connection to location A, I can connect the database using the IP from the tun interface from my computer.

The error I'm getting is `ERROR 2002 (HY000) Can't connect to MySQL server on ip_of_the_nas`.

UPDATE

I made a schematics to clarify my situation further:
[image: Overview of the networks]

Can someone help me ?

Comment: I was thinking something along these lines, that the mysql-client is looking for mysql daemon on that port, instead of being redirected.
Could you give me an example ?

Comment: It is looking for mysql daemon on that port, therefore you need SSH deamon on one port and mysql daemon on *another* (tunneled) one.

Comment: 'That' port is tunneled just for mysql, I use another forwarded port for ssh, is that what you mean ?

Comment: Oops, I see what you mean, [şshport] should be 33006 (corrected)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ssh tunnel open to public?](https://superuser.com/questions/588591/how-to-make-ssh-tunnel-open-to-public)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fragment of the `ss` output

```
127.0.0.1:3306
```

indicates `sshd` listens on the IPv4 port `3306` only on the loopback interface. Your communication from the outside comes via another (non-loopback) interface.

See [`man 5 sshd_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config):

> `GatewayPorts`
>   Specifies whether remote hosts are allowed to connect to ports forwarded for the client. By default, `sshd(8)` binds remote port forwardings to the loopback address. This prevents other remote hosts from connecting to forwarded ports. GatewayPorts can be used to specify that `sshd` should allow remote port forwardings to bind to non-loopback addresses, thus allowing other hosts to connect. The argument may be `no` to force remote port forwardings to be available to the local host only, `yes` to force remote port forwardings to bind to the wildcard address, or `clientspecified` to allow the client to select the address to which the forwarding is bound. The default is `no`.

So you need

- `GatewayPorts yes` in your `sshd_config`; or
- alternatively `GatewayPorts clientspecified` and then *one* of these:

  ```
  ssh -R               :3306:localhost:3306 …  # note the extra `:'
  ssh -R            '*':3306:localhost:3306 …
  ssh -R proper_IP_here:3306:localhost:3306 …
  ```

Don't forget you need to reload/restart `sshd`. Also check if the firewall on the NAS doesn't block the port.

Comment: I was already wondering what was up with that entry to localhost.
So I've changed some things as per your suggestion and now the ss output makes more sense. (I used '*' since it is a connection that will only be made for migrating the data, but as a reference for the future, which ipaddress should replace the asterisk ? The IP of the NAS ? Or the client ?
It is still not working though, it now takes substantially longer before the same error gets thrown, so I guess that's progress ;-)
As for the firewall: iptables is running, but no rules are defined...

Comment: Never mind the last comment. Suddenly it is working. Thank you for bearing with me !!