# SSH tunnel only listens on 127.0.0.1 on remote host

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel

The situation is as described:
Lets say we have a local computer (`10.0.0.5`) with a web server on port 80 and a remote Ubuntu 18.04 server (`1.2.3.4`), when I try tunneling from the local computer to the remote server on port 8080, the ssh tunnel works but only listens on the local IP.

The problem is only the remote server, via `127.0.0.1:8080` can access the server behind the ssh tunnel, whereas I want it to listen on `1.2.3.4:8080` so other people can connect to the local computer via the remote server.

Comment: Seeing the actual command used to start the tunnel may help as well

Comment: I figured it out, check my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ssh tunnel open to public?](https://superuser.com/questions/588591/how-to-make-ssh-tunnel-open-to-public)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem.

By editing the SSH config file (usually `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on Linux), you can set the `GatewayPorts` to `yes` and then it should allow SSH tunnels to listen on the other interfaces.

Comment: Pretty sure you need a `systemctl restart sshd` after this.